# Debugging a static library in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, static-libraries

I am building a static library and am receiving no compiling errors, however, when I link it against a demo project(basic single view app). I cannot step into the methods called from the static library to debug it...

I'm not receiving any runtime errors, but I think that is because it's not being executed due to the fact my NSLogs are not being shown, and it's not returning anything...

Basically, how do I debug a static library I created through the demo app I also created..

What do I do? I need help!!

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To use runtime `debugger` you should add your `static` library project as `subproject` to your sample where you want to debug it.

Make sure that `GENERATE_DEBUG_SYMBOLS` is set to YES (debug mode) for your `static` lib.

In case of using in project compiled `static` library (libYourLib.a) you won't be able step into methods but still should see `NSLog` coming.

Comment: Does *debug mode* mean setting the __Build Configuration__ to __Debug__ in the Scheme window?

Answer (score 7):

If your static library is not a subproject or it is not in the same workspace, first make sure that `GENERATE_DEBUG_SYMBOLS` is set to YES (debug mode), as @Injectios says. Then go to **Breakpoint Navigator**, add a new "**Symbolic Breakpoint**" with the class/method you are interested in, and run your application.

Answer (score 2):

The way I generally do it in my pre-compiled static library is that I would add a breakpoint at `viewDidload` and then when the breakpoint is hit and if we know which methods to add the breakpoint to, I would add a breakpoint like `b <function_name>` and then press continue, and when that function is hit during the execution, it would break and we can use regular lldb options to continue, step over and step into the code.