# iOS: When to choose a Cocoa Touch Static Library or Framework?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, static-libraries

To begin: I read the other questions here, but they are stating that e.g. Swift cannot be used in a Framework or/and Library or are outdated (5 years old).

What are the advantages and downsides of a Cocoa Touch Framework vs. a Cocoa Touch Static Library for achieving this?

I´m trying to share code between two iOS targets, e.g. an iPhone target and an iPad target (Universal target is not wanted here).

If I understand it correctly, the Static Library and the app code will be merged together into one Binary, while the combination of Framework and app code will be two binaries. I guess this means more signing and more DSYM files to upload to crash reporting tools?

Also, a Framework should/could also work standalone while a Static Library always needs other code.

What about Tests, Distribution to the App Store, Debugging (Breakpoints) and compile time? Which option performs better for what task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some clarifications of Static vs Dynamic Frameworks: [iOS Static vs Dynamic frameworks clarifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899799/ios-static-vs-dynamic-frameworks-clarifications)

Language: As for the use of Swift, before you couldn't create a Static Library with it, but from Xcode 9 onwards you can. So I guess Swift vs. ObjC wouldn't be a problem. Haven't found any tutorials on creating Static Libraries with Swift, just for creating Frameworks (for example: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5109-creating-a-framework-for-ios). So maybe a Framework would be easier in terms of finding resources/references.

dSYM: Citing an answer from an Apple Staff: "If you are building the framework as a dependency of your app target, the dSYMs for the framework will be present in the archive you create when archiving the app for distribution. If you are using a framework provided by a vendor that is already compiled, you will need to contact the framework vendor about the dSYMs." (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/70716). As for Static Libraries, they would be less work in terms of the dSYMs you handle. ([Why does not Xcode generate dSYM for static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50604249/why-does-not-xcode-generate-dsym-for-static-library))

Codesigning for Frameworks: "Developer is free to distribute iOS framework without codesigning it as Consumer will re-codesign it anyway, but Developer is forced by Xcode to codesign their framework when they build for iOS device" ([Creating iOS/OSX Frameworks: is it necessary to codesign them before distributing to other developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963294/creating-ios-osx-frameworks-is-it-necessary-to-codesign-them-before-distributin))

As for Tests, adding the Framework or the Static Library on your Unit Testing target's build phases should do the job.

Breakpoints: 
Static Libraries: [Debugging a static library in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512585/debugging-a-static-library-in-xcode)
Frameworks: [Xcode 9 - Framework breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972443/xcode-9-framework-breakpoints)

For what I've read in the links, although Static Libraries might be a little more efficient, Frameworks are a lot less work to set up.